# Silverlight File Upload with Original Creation, Modification & Access Dates

Tags: c#, file-upload, silverlight-5.0

I'm using those methods to upload files,

Client Side:

```
    private void Add(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Multiselect = true;
        OFD.Filter = "Python (*.py)|*.py";
        bool? Result = OFD.ShowDialog();
        if (Result != null && Result == true)
            foreach (var File in OFD.Files)
                mylistbox.Items.Add(File);
    }
    private void Submit(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var File in mylistbox.Items)
            Process(((FileInfo)File).Name.Replace(((FileInfo)File).Extension, string.Empty), ((FileInfo)File).OpenRead());
    }
    private void Process(string File, Stream Data)
    {
        UriBuilder Endpoint = new UriBuilder("http://localhost:5180/Endpoint.ashx");
        Endpoint.Query = string.Format("File={0}", File);

        WebClient Client = new WebClient();
        Client.OpenWriteCompleted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Send(Data, e.Result);
            e.Result.Close();
            Data.Close();
        };
        Client.OpenWriteAsync(Endpoint.Uri);
    }
    private void Send(Stream Input, Stream Output)
    {
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[4096];
        int Flag;

        while ((Flag = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            Output.Write(Buffer, 0, Flag);
        }
    }
```

Server Side:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext Context)
    {
        using (FileStream Stream = File.Create(Context.Server.MapPath("~/" + Context.Request.QueryString["File"].ToString() + ".py")))
        {
            Save(Context.Request.InputStream, Stream);
        }
    }

    private void Save(Stream Input, FileStream Output)
    {
        byte[] Buffer = new byte[4096];
        int Flag;
        while ((Flag = Input.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            Output.Write(Buffer, 0, Flag);
        }
    }
```

My problem is that uploaded files have different **Creation, Modification & Access Dates**.
Why ?

Comment: Can you give an example of the dates? Are the different from the original file that got uploaded?

Comment: Original dates are replaced by today's dates.

Comment: That's because you are creating a new file. I thought you meant that the Creation date on the new file was different from the Modification date on the new file. When you upload a file, you are essentially creating a new file, with duplicated contents.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload a file, you are essentially creating a new file, with duplicated contents.

From your code:

```
using (FileStream Stream = File.Create(Context.Server.MapPath("~/" + Context.Request.QueryString["File"].ToString() + ".py")))
{
    Save(Context.Request.InputStream, Stream);
}
```

The `File.Create` is responsible for the new dates.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998098/getting-the-original-files-create-date-upon-upload) for information on preserving the dates.

Comment: "this solution however, only currently applies to image files"