# jquery file upload module sending extra parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, file, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jquery file upload plugin. I added an extra button to tell the server to finalize everything, this is suppose to send an extra parameter as below:

```
$('.btn-finalize').click(function(){
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType:'json',
        formData:{name:'finalize',value:'1'},
        url: 'server/php/'
       });
});
```

This click handler is called, but no request is getting sent. why?

Comment: I guess it's hard to tell just watching a small piece of code

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin#wiki-how-to-start-uploads-with-a-button-click) advice to inverse `click` and `autoupload` handlers.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    autoUpload: false,
    formData: {
        name: 'finalize',
        value: '1'
    },
    add: function (e, data) {
        $('.btn-finalize').click(function () {
            data.submit();
        })
    },
    done: function (e, data) {    
        console.log(data.formData.name); // Show "finalize" in the console
    }
});
```

[A testing fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fractaliste/MEA58/12/)